# is this nested or non-nested models

Tags: model

I have 2 models,

Y = `a1 + B1*X1 + b2*X2 + e`   (1)

Y = `a2 + B1*X1 + b3*X3 + e`   (2)

are these two model nested? if I impose B2=0 then model 1 doesn't equal model 2. Can I impose B2 = 0 and B3 = 0 to get nested model? or can I conclude they are non-nested?

Thanks

Comment: Did you intend to write both "Y1" and "Y2"? If so, then what might the connection be between them?  If there's no connection, then in what sense are you trying to use "nested"?

Comment: they are same model Y

Answer (score 1):

If by "nested" you mean that all terms of a smaller model occur in a larger model, then no. These are not nested models. Understanding why you want to know whether the models are nested might help people answer your question though.

[Edit- I came across a paper you could take a look at that would define your example as partially nested. You can take a look at it:

Clarke, K.A. (2001), "Testing Nonnested Models of International Relations: Reevaluating Realism," American Journal of Political Science, 45:3, 724-744. ]

Also, regarding you're comment, I suspect that you mean to say that your two models are predicting the same outcome Y, not that they are the same model. While the true outcome Y you're trying to predict might be the same, your estimate of Y will be different depending on which model you use. Therefore you should probably write the LHS of your models as "Y1" and "Y2". [EDIT- under the convention I learned, your LHS would actually be  $\hat Y_1$ and $\hat Y_2$, where the hat indicates that it is an estimate. I guess whuber's comment suggests that it's normal to write the LHS as the variable itself and not the estimate.]

Comment: Although the *estimates* might differ, the response variable is the same.  It would be confusing to give it two different names (which is what the original version of the question did).  One ought to give the *estimates* different names, not the variables themselves.